# Android Executing shell commands programmatically (Non root)

Tags: android, shell, sh

How can I execute shell commands programmatically in java code? I tried this.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("MyCommand");
```

It's working fine for some commands but I wana change directory to `/data/data/mypackage` and it's showing me permissions error, Why is this happening as I have read and write permisisons to my package directory. How can I solve this??

Comment: how do you know you have r/w access to *your package directory*? did you check it or just assumed?

Comment: Don't an app have r/w access to it's own package directory??

Comment: Well I don't know. Is there a documentation saying it has?

Comment: We can  read write package directory without any permission by using android APIs so I am assuming that it should also work...

Comment: I wouldn't rely on such assumption, first make sure you have access to `/data/data/package`, then edit your question accordingly. Also include the command you attempted to run in that directory. Make this a complete question with no room for assumptions, predictions